# Neodatis and duplicities

Tags: java, database, jframe

Neodatis create a new "Pais" when there is an equal one.

I'm working with Neodatis on a GUI. I have a database that contains "Jugadores" and "Pais." The "Jugadores" have an attribute of "Pais". When I want to add a new "Jugadores" to the database with one of the existing "Pais", recreate it in the database, since the query does not return that there is one with the same name.

GUI code:

```
gestionLiga gestionLiga = new gestionLiga();

gestionLiga.altaJugador(txtNombre.getText(), txtDeporte.getText(), txtCiudad.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText()), gestionLiga.sacarPais(txtPais.getText()));
```

gestionLiga.sacarPais code:

```
public Pais sacarPais(String pais)
    {
    odb = ODBFactory.open("EQUIPOS.test");
    IQuery query = new CriteriaQuery(Pais.class, Where.equal("nombre",pais));   
    Objects <Pais> listado = odb.getObjects(query);
    if(listado.size() == 0)
    {
        int contador;
        IQuery query2 = new CriteriaQuery(Pais.class);
        Objects <Pais> listado2 = odb.getObjects(query2);
        contador = listado2.size()+1;
        odb.close();
        return new Pais(contador, pais);
    }
    else
    {
        odb.close();
        return (Pais)listado.getFirst();
    }
}
```

gestionLiga.altaJugador code:

```
public void altaJugador(String nombre, String deporte, String ciudad, int edad, Pais pais)
{
    odb = ODBFactory.open("EQUIPOS.test");
    Jugadores jugador = new Jugadores(nombre, deporte, ciudad, edad, pais);
    odb.store(jugador);
    odb.close();
}
```

Pais class code:

```
class Pais 
{
 private int id;
 private String nombre;

public Pais(){}

public Pais(int id, String nombre) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String toString()
{
    return this.nombre;
}
}
```

Jugadores class code:

```
public class Jugadores 
{

private String nombre, deporte, ciudad;
private int edad;
private Pais pais;
public Jugadores(){} 

public Jugadores(String nombre, String deporte, String ciudad, int edad, Pais pais) 
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.deporte = deporte;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.pais = pais;
}

public String getNombre() 
{
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) 
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDeporte() 
{
    return deporte;
}

public void setDeporte(String deporte) 
{
    this.deporte = deporte;
}

public String getCiudad() 
{
    return ciudad;
}

public void setCiudad(String ciudad) 
{
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}

public int getEdad() 
{
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) 
{
    this.edad = edad;
}

public Pais getPais() {
    return pais;
}

public void setPais(Pais pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "NOMBRE: " + nombre + " - DEPORTE: " + deporte + " - CIUDAD: " + ciudad + " - EDAD: " + edad + " - PAIS: " + pais;
}


}
```

If I enter two players with the same country, the query in theory should return me that there is already a Pais with that name, which should not create a new one, however, enter the IF and create a new one.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey there! A couple things: 1.) could you please show us the `Pais` class code? and 2.) you seem to be mixing languages in your question. It's true that Stack Overflow is predominantly English site, but it would be great if your question could be consistent in using one language (so that we know exactly what part of your code you're referencing), even if that language isn't English :)

Comment: There it is the code, also Jugadores class.
I know I'm mixing languages, the truth is that I should start programming in English, so when I ask questions in the future there will be no problems. Sorry.

Comment: Hey - thanks! To clarify: it's fine if you want to put up code with names in another language (as long as someone could still parse it without knowing that language) - the only real issue is that you talk about the **same** variables (players and countries) in different languages, which makes things hard to understand, especially for someone who only speaks English :)

Comment: F**k me, I didn't see i wrote that there. So sorry, I'm shooting myself :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just don't close odb on sacarPais, then I don't open (because I can't open it twice)on altaJugador. After insert a new Jugador with Pais reference, I close the odb. It's done, a bu*****t.